# Making sure that the textbox is only filled with a value from a dropdown.

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a textbox which is populated upon clicking a `<li>` element in a dropdown. This dropdown is populated by a `ng-repeat` directive on the `<li>` elements. I have a model to filter the `<li>` elements on text input.

I want to make sure that when the textbox loses focus, it is either filled with a value from the dropdown or it is reset to a default value. **(Simply no custom values are accepted.)** Other than checking the value on the text box inside a loop to check for a match in the respective list of items. What other approaches do I have using javascript **(preferably the angular way)**, to easily and effectively address this issue?

(I need the ability to type on the textfield to enable filtering of the dropdown, that and for  many other reasons I think cannot use `<select>` tag.)

Comment: Can you add your code(whatever you tried so far) here?

Comment: Presumably you are already setting the value OK and just want to stop editing. There is no way to **guarantee** that users can't enter any value they like into a form control. However, you can make it more difficult by making the text input readonly, then its value can only be set by script (but users can do that too if they want). Please tell users it's readonly so they don't get frustrated trying to manually edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you still use `select` but go with Angular-UI's `ui-select`:

[Angular-UI ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select)

It's a wrapper for and AngularJS native implementation of [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)